# ¿Cómo pasar todos los ítems seleccionados de un recyclerview a otra actividad?

Tags: android-studio, recyclerview

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación Android en donde el usuario tiene una lista de ítems los cuales puede seleccionar y a su vez des-seleccionar, lo que quiero es obtener los ítems que el usuario seleccione en otra actividad mas exactamente lo que quiero obtener son los datos que tienen estos ítems, en mi caso seria el nombre y el precio del producto, sin embargo no consigo hacerlo debido a que el método *putExtra* del *intent* funciona de forma muy diferente cuando se trata de un *recyclerView* intente varias formas pero tal parece que ninguna funciona para mi código.

Esta vez decidí poner todo el código debido a que, sea mas entendible.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    EditText etBuscador;
    RecyclerView rvLista = null;
    AdaptadorUsuarios adaptador = null;
    List<Usuario> listaUsuarios;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);

        Button btnPasarDatos = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnContinuarTicket);
        btnPasarDatos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            //Aquí debería ir el código del boton que manda los items seleccionados a otra activity
            }
        });

        etBuscador = findViewById(R.id.etBuscador);
        etBuscador.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                filtrar(s.toString());
            }
        });


        rvLista = findViewById(R.id.rvLista);
        rvLista.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3));
        listaUsuarios = new ArrayList<>();

        obtenerUsuarios();

        adaptador = new AdaptadorUsuarios(MainActivity.this, listaUsuarios);
        rvLista.setAdapter(adaptador);

       
    }

    //Metodo para seleccionar los examenes que el usuario quiera
    private List<Usuario> getListData() {
        listaUsuarios = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            listaUsuarios.add(new Usuario("id_examen" + i, "nombre_examen"+ i, "precio_examen" + i, "id_categoria" + i));
        }
        return listaUsuarios;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

    }
    
    //En este metodo obtengo los campos de mi base de datos para posteriormente mostrarlos en el 
    //recyclerview

    public void obtenerUsuarios() {

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, getResources().getString(R.string.URL_USUARIOS),

                response -> {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Examenes");

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            listaUsuarios.add(
                                    new Usuario(
                                            jsonObject1.getString("id_examen"),
                                            jsonObject1.getString("nombre_examen"),
                                            jsonObject1.getString("precio_examen"),
                                            jsonObject1.getString("id_categoria")));
                        }


                        adaptador = new AdaptadorUsuarios(MainActivity.this, listaUsuarios);
                        rvLista.setAdapter(adaptador);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        );

        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    //Metodo para buscar examenes en el recyclerview mediante un searchView
    public void filtrar(String texto) {
        ArrayList<Usuario> filtrarLista = new ArrayList<>();

        for(Usuario usuario : listaUsuarios) {
            if(usuario.getNombreExamen().toLowerCase().contains(texto.toLowerCase())) {
                filtrarLista.add(usuario);
            }
        }

        adaptador.filtrar(filtrarLista);
    }

}
```

Este es el adaptador para el *recyclerview* y el *cardviews* que estoy utilizando, bueno quien ya conoce sobre el tema ya sabe de que va todo esto.

**AdaptadorUsuario.java**

```
public class AdaptadorUsuarios extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdaptadorUsuarios.UsuarioViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    List<Usuario> listaUsuarios;

    public AdaptadorUsuarios(Context context, List<Usuario> listaUsuarios) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listaUsuarios = listaUsuarios;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public UsuarioViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_rv_usuario, viewGroup, false);
        return new UsuarioViewHolder(v);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UsuarioViewHolder usuarioViewHolder, int i) {

        final Usuario user = listaUsuarios.get(i);

        usuarioViewHolder.tvNombre.setText(listaUsuarios.get(i).getNombreExamen());
        usuarioViewHolder.tvPrecio.setText(listaUsuarios.get(i).getPrecioExamen());

        //A partir de aquí comienza la lógica para pintar cada cardView del recyclerView

        usuarioViewHolder.view.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(user.isSelect() ? Color.GRAY : Color.rgb(0, 151, 167)));

        usuarioViewHolder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                user.setSelect(!user.isSelect()); //En mi clase Usuario he creado un método isSelect para 
                                                  //validar si el item esta seleccionado o no y a su vez 
                                                  //obtenerlo claro.
                usuarioViewHolder.view.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(user.isSelect() ? Color.GRAY : Color.rgb(0,151,167)));
                System.out.println(user.isSelect());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        
            return listaUsuarios == null ? 0 : listaUsuarios.size();

    }

    public class UsuarioViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView tvNombre, tvPrecio;
        public View view;
        ImageView imageView;
        int idCate;

        public UsuarioViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            view = itemView;
            tvNombre = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvNombre);
            tvPrecio = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrecio);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgItem);
            idCate = itemView.getId();

        }
    }

    public void filtrar(ArrayList<Usuario> filtroUsuarios) {
        this.listaUsuarios = filtroUsuarios;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

**En conclusión**

Todo el código que he mostrado no es lo único que tengo pero es la esencia de lo que estoy desarrollando y en donde me he quedado estancado, mi próxima función es obtener todos los ítems que el usuario seleccione en otra actividad lo cual no lo consigo.

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: hay una librería para eso llamada RecyclerView-Selection. [Esta](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview-custom#select) es la guia de cómo usarla

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo!! me ayudo mucho!

Comment: muestra en una respuesta como lo implementaste para ayudar a otros que tengan un caso similar

Comment: Claro, cuando termine de implementarlo lo aré.